# Problems with Sharing Colab Notebooks

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I've just encountered a strange issue with google-colab notebooks I shared: After clicking, instead of opening the notebook in the Colab app, only raw code is displayed:

[image]

In some cases one could open the notebook by clicking on the link given on top of the picture. In other cases, the code had to be downloaded and then manually imported into Colab. I find this strange because previously I could simply click on the links and notebooks were correctly opened inside the Colab app. I've set sharing permissions appropriately so that anyone with the share link can view it.

Has there been a change to this or is this some sort of bug? Thanks!

Comment: Your screenshot looks like Google Drive preview. As of today, I see only GSuite files (Docs, Sheets, etc) open in their respective applications when clicked from GDrive. For others including Colab files and Jupyter notebooks, clicking defaults to showing a preview like your screenshot. So I think you just need to get used to it: know when you are in preview mode and just click "Open with Google Colaboratory" to open.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is displayed using Drive Preview, if you click the 'open with Google Colaboratory', the code will be displayed normally.